# Create multiple key/value pairs in DataStore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm working with Python and Google Cloud DataStore and have a lot of key/value pairs to be stored for each entity, like this:

Key: BEDROOMS, Value: 3

Key: GARAGES, Value: 2

Key: EXCLUSIVE ,Value: True

Key: EXPIRES, Value: 2015-05-26

etc.

I have to filter that later, e.g.: fetch all entities that have BEDROOMS > 2 and GARAGES > 1.

What is the best way to store that on Google's DataStore? I read the documents regarding [data types](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#types) and didn't find a good way to do that.

Comment: why can't you create the fields for the entity? i don't get what's the main problem here.
PS: have a look at this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass

Comment: @EsseTi Oh, that's what I was looking for. I had not noticed that Expando class in the documents. Please, post your solution as an answer for me to accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the [expando class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass), which you can use to store arbitrary field at runtime. 
PS: check how to do [query with expando](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries)

> If your model is an Expando, then your filter can use GenericProperty, the class Expando uses for dynamic properties

[Polymodel](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass) may also work, but it depends on your database structure.